# How do I make my loading screen stop and go into my main page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, nav

How do I make my loading screen stop and then go into the main page or my website?

Also update code down here:

// begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false

// language: lang-css

```
.navbar__link {
  position: static;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}


}
// you don't need to add class to a tag, it can be selected by following way
.navbar>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
}
.header {
  display: flex;
  // make the header take all space of body
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  // make navbar take all space that remains after the logo
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  // make the navbar move left side else it will not be in complete middlle
  transform: translate(-100px);
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.loading-screen {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.logo {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}
.loading-bar {
  width: 130px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 22px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.loading-bar::before {
  content: '';
  width: 68px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  left: -34px;
  animation: blackbar 1.5s infinite ease;
}
@keyframes blackbar {
  50% {
    left: 96px;
  }
}
```

```
<header>
  <div style="float: left; padding-right: 10px;">
    <a href="/"><img width='200' height='50' src='Icons/logo home.png' /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar" style="justify-content: center;">
    <a href="discovery.html" class="navbar__link">
      <span class="material-icons">whatshot</span>
    </a>
    <a href="profile.html" class="navbar__link">
      <span class="material-icons">person_outline</span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <!-- Loading Screen -->

  <div class="loading-screen">
    <div class="loading-animation">
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
      <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
      <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="90px" height="90px" viewBox="0 0 90 90" enable-background="new 0 0 90 90" xml:space="preserve">  <image id="image0" width="90" height="90" x="0" y="0"
              xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFoAAABaAQAAAAAQ03yvAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJN
          AAB6JQAAgIMAAPn/AACA6QAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF2+SX8VGAAAAAmJLR0QAAd2KE6QAAAAJcEhZ
          cwAACxMAAAsTAQCanBgAAAAHdElNRQfkBwsBJxoCRYkNAAAAmElEQVQ4y2P4jwAHGEY5w5zzhx2J
          8xPO3n+A4TMq5/CP2vYPFfZMzCCO5XOb4vPf54Bkfv6veT/n9/3/d0CcP3Y15+f+ng/h/OdjOCAL
          5NyzB3GO1Z//+3v+D3l+EOcZmPP4/mME5/n9zyDOc/vnf3/ffz4fxPl+3u753d/nn8/9PP8Awwf5
          Az9kf38oiOE/PBjCbZRDNw4Awv38T7O+5eEAAAAldEVYdGRhdGU6Y3JlYXRlADIwMjAtMDctMTFU
          MDE6Mzk6MjYrMDM6MDDkTb6MAAAAJXRFWHRkYXRlOm1vZGlmeQAyMDIwLTA3LTExVDAxOjM5OjI2
          KzAzOjAwlRAGMAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
          </svg>
      <div class="loading-bar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</header>
```

JS:

```
function handlePageLoaded(){
  document.getElementsByClassName("loading-screen")[0].style.display = "none";
}
```

Updates will go beneath this:

Update 1: None of them work :(.

All 3 answers sadly didn't work, it wont redirect to the page for some odd reason. But we will keep on trying :D!

Update 2: Still doesn't work. I tried JS and I tried to change class to id but it broke so I put it back to class :(.

You guys could change the code if you wish too.

Update 4: I tried everything they don't work sadly, but I think it has to do with the code because it wont load into the site it's just stuck on loading.

Update 5: Update codepen if you want to see the code. Still doesn't work :(.

[FIXED]

Comment: I'm going to guess your new to web development the best way to implement a loading page is to have the loading screen and the web page is the same HTML file what you are trying to do is not a functional loading screen. you also have to use js to see when the page has loaded and the only way to do that is if your loading screen and webpage are in the same HTML document

Comment: They are, I don't know why it doesn't work tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do the follow:

1.In your `<body />` markup:

```
<body onload="handlePageLoaded()">
 ...
</body>
```

2.In your javascript file:

```
function handlePageLoaded(){
  document.getElementsByClassName("loading-screen")[0].style.display = "none";
}
```

The function `handlePagaLoaded` will be called when the body's page is completely loaded.

I recommend use `id` instead of class in this case for your loading screen.

in this case the function would be:

```
function handlePageLoaded(){
      document.getElementById("loading-screen").style.display = "none";
    }
```

You can use `document.getElementById("loading-screen").style.visibility= "hidden";` too because your "loading-screen" `position` is fixed.

Hope it helps!

Comment: There is the test:
https://codepen.io/MartinGK/pen/PoZaENo

Comment: Oh! but it doesn't work on the site for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

To check if your page is completely loaded use `document.readyState === "complete"` or `window.onload`.

`document.readyState` has three possible values `loading`, `interactive`, `complete`.

`loading`: The document is loading.

`interactive`: The document has finished loading but images, stylesheets and frames are still loading.

`complete`: The document has completely loaded including.

js:

```js
// check if page is loaded 
if(document.readyState === "complete") {
  // make loading screen go away
  document.getElementById('loading').style.display = none
}
```

This will not redirect but you should try to avoid redirecting because it will make the page speed quicker and gives an overall better feel and experience to the website (plus redirecting kind of defeats the purpose of having a loading screen).

don't forget to add an `id` attribute to the `loading-screen` div so you can target the element in js.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle page loaded with *window.onload*.
We can assign here a function that hides your loader when page is loaded.

```
window.onload = () => {
    const loader = document.querySelector('.loading-screen');
    loader.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Or in case you need to redirect to another page, you can do it this way

```
window.onload = () => {
    window.location.replace("somethingAmazing.html")
}
```

If you want it to have a delay (let's say page loads quick but you want your animations takes 3 seconds and you want it to play complete before moving to content), let's try this:

```
window.onload = setTimeout(() => {
    window.location.replace("somethingAmazing.html")
}, 3000)
```

You can change the *3000* with the amount of miliseconds you want it to wait

Comment: Do I add a number in the brackets?

Comment: No. In this example it will run automatically after page loaded. If you want to add a delay in case the page loads too quick and you want your loader to least a few seconds, you can wrap it into a setTimeout as show on third example on my answer.